# Validate XHTML folder for Epub3

Tags: xml, xhtml, epub, epub3

I need to validate XHTML folder before including in EPUB3. 
Epub3 validator performs the check after creation of epub. I need to validate before , so i dont have to waste the wait time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the W3C validator online: http://validator.w3.org/

You can also download it, to run it locally: http://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html

Also, if your file names end in .xhtml, you can preview them in Firefox, which has a strict XTHML parser and it will provide you with the line and column number of the first error encountered (if any).

Comment: And so will Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can run epubcheck on a directory tree. Check out the manual.
In any case, building an EPUB is a quick zip operation..so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can go:

1. pack your contents to a ePub file, and then upload to https://github.com/idpf/epubcheck for validation. (But it supports 10MB or lower only)
2. download the validator to your local machine: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.idpf
   I'm using [epubcheck-4.0.0-alpha3]. It's good.

Call the command like this in your php code:
java -jar epubcheck.jar "C:\testing.epub" -v "3.0" -out "report.xml"

You can then read the [report.xml] for the validation report.